# java program i am getting exception which not perfect

Tags: xcode

I am getting an error for not defining withdraw it is a method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 class Bankaccount{
    class LessBalanceException extends Exception
    {
    int acc_bal=0;      

    public String toString()
    {
    return "low balance min bal should be 1000";
    }

public void withdraw(int debitMoney) throws LessBalanceException
    {

    if(acc_bal>1000)  
    {
        acc_bal = acc_bal - debitMoney;
    }
    else    
        throw new LessBalanceException();
    }
    }
public static void main(String args[])
    {

    Bankaccount a= new Bankaccount();
    try
    {  
        a.withdraw(2200);
    }
    catch(LessBalanceException e)
    {
        System.out.println( e);
    }
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: The method withdraw(int) is undefined for the type
>   Bankaccount

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method withdraw(int) is undefined for the type Bankaccount

Comment: I am getting an error for not defining withdraw it is a method.